# Obtaining a orthonormal matrix with 2 columns given

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I have to create a orthonormal square matrix whose first row and last row, say $T_1$ and $T_N$ are given. Now what should be done to get the remaining columns of the matrix? The *Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization* works if the first row was given but providing two rows as constant makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find an $n \times n$ matrix. Suppose the given rows are $v$ and $w$. Presumamably $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal and both have norm 1. Let $u_1=v^T, u_2=w^T.$ Extend $\{u_1,u_2\}$ to a set $\{u_1,u_2,u_3, ... ,u_n\}$ of linearly independent coumn vectors in $\mathbb R^n.$ [You can choose $u_3, ... ,u_n$ among the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n.$] Let $$u_3'=u_3-\frac{u_3 \bullet u_1}{u_1 \bullet u_1}u_1-\frac{u_3 \bullet u_2}{u_2 \bullet u_2}u_2$$ $$u_4'=u_4-\frac{u_4 \bullet u_1}{u_1 \bullet u_1}u_1-\frac{u_4 \bullet u_2}{u_2 \bullet u_2}u_2-\frac{u_4 \bullet u_3'}{u_3' \bullet u_3'}u_3'$$ Continue thus until you have $n$ orthogonal column-vectors $u_1,u_2,u_3', ... ,u_n'. $ Let $$u_i''=\frac{u_i'}{||u_i'||}, 3 \le i \le n$$ Let A be the matrix whose columns are $u_1,u_2,u_3'' ...,u_n''.$ Interchange columns 2 and $n$ of the matrix $A$ to give the matrix $B.$ Let $C=B^T.$ Then $C$ is your desired matrix.

Comment: Now,how do I generate the linearly independent vectors $u_3$, $u_4$,... ? It would be a bit difficult in this case with two predefined rows of the matrix.

Comment: @Divyayan Dey:Extend u_1,u_2 to a basis the same way you would extend any linearly independent set to a basis. Let e_i be the column-vector with 1 in position i and all other entries 0. Here's a pseudo-program. S:={u_1,u_2};. i:=1; while (card(S)<n) do if e_i not in S then S:=SU{e_i}; i:=i+1; end do; So just keep throwing in members of a standard basis provided each vector you throw in is not in the span of what you already have.